# Numbering Theorems/Definitions in Lyx according to Subsection, Line Breaks after Text

Tags: lyx, theorems, amsthm, lyx-layouts

I am currently using Document > Settings > Modules > Theorems (Numbered by Type within Sections) in Lyx.

However, I need my theorems/definitions to be numbered according to subsection instead. i.e.

2 Introduction

2.1 Subsection ...

Definition 2.1.1

Theorem 2.1.2

2.2 Subsection 2

Theorem 2.2.1

Additionally, I also want the text after the labels to be in a new line (instead of continuing after the bold text), i.e.

Definition 2.2.2

The definition of formula is...

I would also like to state that I am rather new to lyx so I am not familiar with editing TeX code (if required) in the editor so detailed steps would really be appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit 1: MWE (I removed mostly font related code)

```
% Preview source code

#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
theorems-ams-bytype
theorems-sec-bytype
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
\begin_inset CommandInset toc
LatexCommand tableofcontents

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\paragraph_spacing onehalf
\noindent
\begin_inset Newpage newpage
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
\paragraph_spacing onehalf
\noindent
Title
\series bold
 1
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
numberwithin{equation}{section}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
setlength{
\backslash
parindent}{1.5pt}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
\paragraph_spacing onehalf
\noindent
Title 2
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsection
\paragraph_spacing onehalf
\noindent
Sub 1
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsection
\paragraph_spacing onehalf
\noindent
Sub 2
\end_layout

\begin_layout Definition
\noindent
My first definition
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know whether it's possible from within LyX, but here is what you have to add  to you preamble to obtain it:

```
\newtheoremstyle{break}%
{5pt}{4pt}% spaces added before and after the environment
{\itshape}{}%
{\bfseries}{}% % Note that final punctuation is omitted.
{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]

\newtheoremstyle{defbreak}%
{5pt}{4pt}% spaces added before and after the environment
{\upshape}{}%
{\bfseries}{}% % Note that final punctuation is omitted.
{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{defbreak}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[subsection]
```

[image]

Here is the full code (slightly modified):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{break}%
{5pt}{4pt}% spaces added before and after the environment
{\itshape}{}%
{\bfseries}{}% % Note that final punctuation is omitted.
{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]

\newtheoremstyle{defbreak}%
{5pt}{4pt}% spaces added before and after the environment
{\upshape}{}%
{\bfseries}{}% % Note that final punctuation is omitted.
{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{defbreak}
\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}[subsection]

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{A first subsection}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{thm}
  A silly test theorem. A silly test theorem. A silly test theorem. A silly test theorem. A silly test theorem.
\end{thm}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{Def}
 This is a \texttt{defbreak} style example. Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
\end{Def}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Received two errors:

1) Latex Error: Command \defn already defined

2) Latex Error: Missing \begin {Document}

Comment: 1) Maybe internally,  LyX has a `\defn`command (or a `defn` environment). Change it to something else that isn't defined,You may try `Def`. 2) I posted only what has to be added to the preamble, not a full compilable code. If you want, I can post the full code of my test file.

Comment: I added the code you posted to my latex preamble and got those errors. Does the source code I posted above in the original comment help in identifying what should be added to the preamble instead? I have a feeling the AMS modules defines a definition format and I cannot just add a preamble to overwrite it.

Comment: As I said, I do not know Lyx. What I can say is is works as a pure  LaTeX code. From what you posted (which sems to be specific to LyX=, I'm not sure Lyx loads the `amsthm` package. Try adding this package.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution would require make your own module, but a poor's man solution could be:

1) Not load any module.

2) Insert this in <kbd>Document</kbd> > <kbd>Stetings...</kbd> > <kbd>LaTeX Preamble</kbd>

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{xxx}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\scshape\bfseries}{:}%
{\newline}{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{(#3)}\smallskip}%
\theoremstyle{xxx}
\newtheorem{xxx}{\protect\theoremname}[subsection]
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Smart theorem}
```

3) Make your your theorem with `\begin{xxx} ... \end{xxx}` in a ERT box (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) or alternatively make two ERT boxes for `\begin{xxx}` and `\end{xxx}` respectively and left the theorem text as a normal paragraph.

The result must be equivalent to this LaTeX source code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{xxx}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\scshape\bfseries}{:}%
{\newline}{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{(#3)}\smallskip}
\theoremstyle{xxx}
\newtheorem{xxx}{\protect\theoremname}[subsection]
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Smart theorem}
\begin{document}
\section{xxx}
Bla bla bla ...
\subsection{adasd}
\begin{xxx}
Bla bla bla ...
\end{xxx}
Bla bla bla ...
\end{document}
```

Obviously, you can change the style `xxx` to some name more meaningful, as well as the arguments of `\newtheoremstyle` to fit more to your desired layout. Run `texdoc amsmath` for information about the arguments.

Comment: Opps, I do not see that Bernard already showed the same solution. I left because is more LyX-new use oriented, though.